# Raspberry pi error: "module ' opencv ' has no attributes "

Tags: linux, python

I am using python 3.6.3 , opencv version 4.0.0 and Rpi 3 B. I have successfully installed opencv , however when I run the following code I get an error at every step where I have used open cv. for eg.

- `image=cv2.imread('badfan_spec.png',0)`
  Error: module opencv has no attribute 'imread'.
- `ax = cv2.calcHist([x],[0],None,[10],[0,256])`
  Error: module opencv has no attribute 'calcHist'.
  And so on.
  I have tried to search for an answer of this question but none of them worked for me.
  I have also tried reinstalling opencv but still the error is not gone.
  Please suggest me a suitable solution.

Code:

```
import scipy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.io.wavfile
import  opencv as cv2
import numpy as np
%matplotlib inline

sample_rate, X = scipy.io.wavfile.read('badfan246.wav')
print (sample_rate, X.shape,X )
image_spec=plt.specgram(X[:,0], Fs=sample_rate, xextent=(0,30))
plt.savefig('badfan_spec')
plt.show()
image=cv2.imread('badfan_spec.png',0)
#image = cv2.cvtColor(image_spec, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
#gray=cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)sns.kdeplot(x, bw=4, label="bw: 4")
cropped = image[52:252, 61:390]
#cv2.imshow('gray',gray)
#cropped=image[50:252,50:500]
cv2.imshow('cropped',cropped)
x=cropped.ravel()
ax = cv2.calcHist([x],[0],None,[10],[0,256])
plt.plot(ax)
plt.show()
ay1=np.array(ax)
maxes = []
for i in range (2, len(ax)-1):
    if (ay1[i-1] < ay1[i] and ay1[i] > ay1[i+1]):
        maxes.append(ay1[i])
print("maxes",len(maxes))
if len(maxes)==1:
    print("good motor")
else:
    print("bad motor")

cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [this](https://www.learnopencv.com/install-opencv-4-on-ubuntu-16-04/) site as a reference, you should import open cv using `import cv2` and not the way you have done before.
For example:

```
Python 3.5.6 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Aug 26 2018, 16:05:27) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import opencv2 as cv2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'opencv2'
>>> import cv2
>>>
```